# Exibir erro ao carregar pagina com url nao encontrada

Tags: php, javascript

Gostaria de saber se é possível cria um iframe com erro de URL
ex: caso nao encontra-se a url tipo aquele erro do navegador quando o site esta fora ou a rede esta desconectada.

Comment: Podes explicar melhor? Queres que no caso se o utilizador abrir uma página que não existe mostre esse erro numa iFrame? como funciona a navegação no teu site?

Comment: No caso o cliente vai ficar com um arquivo html dentro dele vai esta a iframe

Comment: "No caso o cliente vai ficar com um arquivo html dentro dele vai esta a iframe", desculpa mas preciso de uma explicação mais completa. Talvez seja o meu Português de Portugal que impede compreender a tua ideia completamente mas se puderes explica ainda melhor.  [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas formas de você criar uma página de erro para substituir a página erro padrão do browser quando não existe determinado arquivo na pasta.

Uma boa opção seria criar uma array de páginas que existem no seu site dentro da  sua index. Se na url não existir essa página, ele inclui uma página de erro "mais bonita".

vejamos com essa url:

> www.site.com.br?pagina=hacker

**index.php**

```
     // vamos verificar se existe o $_GET['pagina']
    // no caso desta url esta condição é verdadeira então ele entra no primeiro if
    if(isset($_GET['pagina']){

    // criaremos um array das páginas que existem no site.
    $paginasExistentes = array('home', 'produto', 'contato');

     // agora vamos verificar se a página $_GET['pagina'] está dentro das $paginasExistentes
       // ( nesta url não vai estar, pois o valor dela é "hack"

       $paginaUrl = $_GET['pagina'];           

       if(array_search($paginaUrl, $paginasExistentes) != false ){

       // se a condição for verdadeira, inclua a página selecionada

       include($paginasExistentes.".html");

       } else {

       // se não inclua a página erro

       include("paginaErro.html");

       }

    } **else** {

    // se não existir o $_GET['pagina'], você precisa analisar a url:

    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        if($url == 'index.php' || $url == ''){

         // se a url for index.php ou vazia inclua pagina home            

          include("home.html");

        } else {

        // se não inclua a página erro             

        include("paginaErro.html");

        }

    }
```

Outro exemplo:

> www.site.com.br/hacker

nesta url, a primeira condição "if" do código é false, então ele irá para o último else e incluirá a página erro

na sua página erro você pode incluir o iframe que necessita

espero ter ajudado